# Помогите спарсить этот xml в android

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlparser

Есть такой xml файл. Как его можно спарсить?

```
<ArrayOfProduct
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApiSolution.Data.Entity">
    <Product>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Iphone</Name>
        <Price>30</Price>
        <Qty>3</Qty>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Name>Samsung</Name>
        <Price>12</Price>
        <Qty>4</Qty>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <Name>LG</Name>
        <Price>21</Price>
        <Qty>7</Qty>
    </Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
Document doc = builder.parse(inputSource);

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Product");
Log.d("TAG", "----------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(i);

        Log.d("TAG", "\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            Log.d("TAG", "Id: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Id").item(0).getTextContent());
            Log.d("TAG", "Name: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent());
            Log.d("TAG", "Price: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Price").item(0).getTextContent());
            Log.d("TAG", "Qty: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Qty").item(0).getTextContent());
         }
     }
```